# Multi-threaded access to database with non-blocking main-thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to use sqlite in a multi-threaded critical application where the main thread should not be blocked. At the moment I have two topologies in my mind shown as snippets, which one is better  and why? Option I seems more simplistic but I also want remote distributed systems to query the database through sockets for which option II seems more realistic. Are there other approaches?

option I - using an atomic flag

```
   class database_t
   {
   private:
       static std::atomic<bool> main_busy_flag_; // to pre-empt worker threads
       std::mutex mutex_;

   };

   class watchdog_thread
   {
       void use_database()
       {
           while (database_t::is_main_busy()) { this_thread::sleep_for(100);}
           // lock mutex and do something
       }
   };
```

option II - using priority queue

```
  typedef pair<int, query_t> priority_query_t;    

   class database_t
   {
   private:
       priority_queue<priority_query_t> queries_;
       list <query_result_t> query_results_;
   public:
       void insert_query(int priority,query_t query );
       void process_queries();
   };
```

Comment: What do you mran by non-blocking?  As in, even if other threads are suspended at arbitrary points the main thread makes forward progress guaranteed, or it just does not wait very long?

Comment: Yes main thread should not wait very long as watchdog thread will continuously query the database

Comment: I wouldbuse future-likes.  Maybe implemented as a queue behind the scenes.  If the main thread has a message loop, the futures can be then-chained to deliver their payload via message.

Comment: @Yakk: Use of future as an alternative sounds interesting, can you please elaborate a bit.